# Java Weka new Instances of a list of attributes of Instances index

Tags: java, machine-learning, attributes, weka

I have a `trainingSet` with 15 attributes. I want to create a new `Instances` object out of the dataset `trainingSet`, but with specific attributes indexes (from the `trainingSet` attributes).

For example I want to create a new `Instances` object with the indexes `{1,2,3}`, so the new Instances I'll have, will the same dataset, but with only the attributes at index 1,2,3 (and the target index of course).

Something like:

```
int[] desiredIndexes = {1,2,3}
newTrainingSet = new Instances(trainingSet, desiredIndexes)
```

So `newTrainingSet` will have the attributes from the attributes at `trainingSet` at index 1,2,3 and the target attribute.

I looked through the API, but I found only an option to delete one attribute. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [`Remove`](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/Remove.html#setAttributeIndices-java.lang.String-) function. Just remember to use `invert`.

Some examples: [here](http://book2s.com/java/api/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/remove/setattributeindicesarray-1.html)